# Does convergence in $L^p(U)$ and $L^q(U)$ implies same limit.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $1\le p<q<\infty$ such that $x_n\to x_p$ in $L^p(U)$ and $x_n\to x_q$ in $L^q(U)$ for some open set $U$.Does the limit $x_p = x_q$ a.e?

I have two approach to do it,if $U$ is bonded ,the result holds.since convergence in $L^q(U)$ implies convergence in $L^p(U)$.Hence the limit is unique in normed space.

For unbounded case,extract almost everywhere convergence subsequence then limit must coinside a.e.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes. Even the unbounded argument also works for bounded $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. (Formally) the uniqueness of the limit (in the single space you are considering) comes from the fact that normed spaces are $T_2$. But, the main argument in both cases is the subsequence that converges almost everywhere to the limit function. Both the bounded and unbounded cases work.

Look at this for more: [Convergence of a sequence in two different $L_p$ spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691020/convergence-of-a-sequence-in-two-different-l-p-spaces)